# Iframe scrollbar not at right of page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to make the litle bit of space on the right of the scrollbar disapear. The page is here: http://idreesinc.com/pinged.html . If you open it up you can see that here is about 1 mm of space between the two iframes.

I want to know if i can fix this. I had to make the iframes 49.892% or something otherwise they would stack vertical not horizontal. Is there anyway to fix this? Sorry for the vague question but I is the best I can explain it.

Comment: I get a 404. Put something up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: i forgot to put .html at the end

Answer (score 0):

Make the width `50%`, add `box-sizing: border-box` (or remove the border) and make sure there is no whitespace in between the two `<iframe>` tags.

I can't advise any further because your link is broken.

Comment: Oh crud i forgot to put .html at the eend